# Redirect to another activity at particular time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i'm developing an app in which i need to redirect from home activity to login activity daily exactly at 11:59 pm. can anyone help me how can i do it. i have tried the below code.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(yourIntent);
        }
}, 4000);
```

Comment: You know you are using a CountDown timer and not AlarmManager, right ??

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html read this article. Do you guys even google?

Comment: yes, i'm using  CountDown timer, please give me an example using alarm manager.

Comment: hi mrid, i have seen your link, but i was unable to understand what is AlarmReceiver.class. Can you explain me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)  allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running.

This code will start `YourActivity` at 11.59pm

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();

/* setting time */
timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intent);
```